# Automation tool for Angularjs and HTML5 desktop application in Electron

Tags: automated-testing, uiautomation, desktop-application

we have a desktop application that is developed using Angular js and HTML5 over atom framework ([Electron](https://electronjs.org/)). I have used UFT 12.53 and Test complete 12.31 and unable to identify object properties. These tool identify the complete window as a single winObject (class name). Can anyone help me which automation tool can help me for UI automation for such desktop application screen.

Comment: Have you tried [Protractor](https://www.protractortest.org/#/) which is official Angular's E2E testing framework.

Comment: Mine is desktop application. I read about Protractor, but I think this can handle web browsed application.

Comment: The Atom framework is called Electron. Atom is an editor build with it.

Answer (score 2):

The Electron framework has its own testing tool called [Spectron](https://electronjs.org/spectron).

> An open source framework for easily writing integrations tests for
>   your Electron app. Spectron sets up and tears down your app and allows
>   it to be test-driven remotely with full support for the Electron APIs.
>   Built on top of ChromeDriver and WebDriverIO.
>
> https://electronjs.org/spectron

Answer (score -1):

[Winium](https://blog.testproject.io/2016/12/22/open-source-test-automation-tools-for-desktop-applications/) check this out there is list of tools for windows applications

Winium is a new open source framework, that’s based on Selenium and consists of 3 parts:

Supports test automation on Windows applications.
 Supports test automation on Windows Phone operating system context (home button, notifications bar, toggles etc.)
 Supports test automation on Windows Phone applications.
Pros:

In case you are already using Selenium WebDriver and familiar with its API, using  Winium is straightforward.

Cons:

As a result of it’s being a new project, few struggles come in the way. Its API still isn’t complete and not on the same maturity level as other tools in this category.

Bottom line: In case you are considering Winium, my advice is to wait until it’s more baked.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/26018)

Comment: @MilinPatel he only asked for tools

Comment: I'm sure you can explain why Winium will be well suited to serve the purpose of this question.

Comment: Winium is for testing "Windows Desktop (WPF, WinForms) Apps", according to the documentation. Electron apps work differently. As the OP described you will see only one interact-able element/object in the window, not the sub elements.

Answer (score -2):

For UI automation of desktop application, the preferable desktop automation tool is Winium which is used to automate window based application. To inspect the elements of windows you can use UIspy.exe tool. Sometimes developer did not define an element in an application, in that case, you can ask developers to add some elements in the application so you can automate it.

Well, in case you want detailed information about winium and how it works you can check out this blog written by my colleague - https://www.bugraptors.com/winium-automation-tool/

Comment: Preferable to who? Any why choose Winium over AutoIT, Ranorex, or Sikuli?

Comment: Winium is for testing "Windows Desktop (WPF, WinForms) Apps", according to the documentation. Electron apps work differently. As the OP described you will see only one interact-able element/object in the window, not the sub elements.